# Союз или союзное слово

Tags: пунктуация

Какие выделенные слова являются союзами?

1)Я вам уже подробно рассказал, **почему** так произошло.

2)**Пока** отложим наши споры: нужно дождаться решения жюри.

3)И нет величия там, **где** нет простоты, красоты и правды.

4)Всякое дело нужно любить, **чтобы** хорошо его делать.

5)Она посмотрела на меня, **как** матери смотрят на маленьких детей.

Answer (score 5):

1)Я вам уже подробно рассказал, ПОЧЕМУ так произошло.
3)И нет величия там, ГДЕ нет простоты, красоты и правды.
В этих предложениях ПОЧЕМУ и ГДЕ --- союзные слова, выполняющие служебную функцию соединения главной и придаточной частей (такую же, какую выполняют подчинительные союзы), а по своим морфологическим свойствам эти слова --- обстоятельственные наречия: ПОЧЕМУ обозначает причину действия и поэтому в придаточной части  является обстоятельством причины, а ГДЕ --- место действия и поэтому в придаточной части является обстоятельством места. Они имеют и все другие наречные признаки: это неизменяемые слова, они относятся к глаголам, синтаксическая связь --- примыкание.

2)ПОКА отложим наши споры: нужно дождаться решения жюри. В этом предложении ПОКА --- обстоятельственное наречие со значением "в течение некоторого времени, впредь до чего-н."

4)Всякое дело нужно любить, ЧТОБЫ хорошо его делать. ЧТОБЫ --- подчинительный целевой  союз, используется в сложноподчиненных предложениях с придаточной ЦЕЛИ (// С ТЕМ ЧТОБЫ, ДЛЯ ТОГО ЧТОБЫ, ЗАТЕМ ЧТОБЫ, С ТОЙ ЦЕЛЬЮ ЧТОБЫ).

5)Она посмотрела на меня, КАК матери смотрят на маленьких детей. КАК --- сравнительный союз, который используется для соединения главной и придаточной сравнительной в сложноподчиненном предложении. Этот союз устанавливает сходство предметов, явлений в придаточной и главной частях, причем сравнение мыслится как достоверное.

Таким образом, СОЮЗАМИ являются слова ЧТОБЫ и КАК в предложениях 4 и 5.

Answer (score 3):

В предложении 4 и 5. В четвертом употреблен союз *чтобы* , легко заменяется на *для того чтобы*.  В пятом - сравнительный союз *"как"* (*точно, словно,будто, как будто*).

В остальных предложениях - наречия.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку вопрос стоит "союз или союзное слово", то и отвечаю строго на него.
И то и другое соединяет предложения. Хотя разница не всегда хорошо видна, но она в том, что первый не является членом предложения.

1 - наречие, союзное слово, в роли обстоятельства (причины). 
2 - наречие, союзным словом не является, так как предложения не соединяет и употреблено в основной функции обстоятельства.
3 - наречие, союзное слово, в роли обстоятельства (где? - там) 
4-5 - союзы.

Comment: Я почему-то вижу только вопрос, заголовок как-то проходит мимо.  Все верно.